# How to find MAX RAM in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

How to find the maximum RAM a computer can be extended upto in powershell.
I tried using

```
 $colItems3 = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_OperatingSystem"
```

but the answer is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For installed RAM you want:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Where {$_.MemoryType -ge 20} | 
    Measure Capacity -sum
```

Look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info on MemoryType.

For the MAX amount of RAM the system will handle, I *think* this is supposed to get you that.  However, I don't think that means the OS or the motherboard would necessarily handle that much memory.  I see nothing on the Win32_MotherboardDevice that shows max RAM.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray | Where {$_.Use -eq 3} | 
    Foreach {($_.MaxCapacity*1KB)/1GB}
```

Here's the [MSDN page for Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This isnt the maximum RAM

Answer (score 0):

```
    $colItems3 = get-wmiobject -class "win32_PhysicalMemoryArray"  -computername $strComputer
       foreach ($objItem3 in $colItems3)
       {
       $e3=($colItems3.MemoryDevices)* 2
             write-host "Free Physical Memory :  " $e3 'GB'

   }
```

This is not correct but atleast near one

Answer (score 0):

Try: `gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem | % {$_.MaxProcessMemorySize / 1MB}` in Powershell.exe